# Apache sitemap generator to generate more than 150K URLs & daily 2K URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, sitemap

I have a big WordPress installation more than 150K post about 2K daily posts 3 months ago i used [Google Sitemap Generator](http://code.google.com/p/googlesitemapgenerator/downloads/list) but unfortunatley it is not working with `CENTOS 6`

It is really very  good because it is using only about 2M.B of RAM & generate all links

So i need to generate my sitemaps without using a lot of memory from my server

I searched more & more for an apache module but didn't found a one

Comment: Did you search on the wordpress modules side? Seeems to me that this is more something the application should handle, and not the webserver.

Comment: I found before a WordPress plugin `Google Sitemap Generator` but it is not worked for me because the big number of posts & also used a lot of RAM so it is down my server

Comment: ask the module creator for a batch mode, maybe.

Comment: `Google Apache Sitemap Generator` unfortunatley didn't updated since 2009 no any information about updates no body replied to forum threads